# List array of values from mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am having a mongo document like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56af2ca2eb91bd4721443037"),
    "username" : "xxxxxx",
    "password" : "02adcec2263d2127269fcd769c33f029",
    "firstName" : "yyyyy",
    "lastName" : "zzzz",
    "email" : "xxxxyyyy.m@gmail.com",
    "userVerified" : "1",
    "userType" : "user",
    "__v" : 0,
    "userGroup" : [
        {
            "groupName" : "nodeJs",
            "groupAssigned" : "No",
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b086ccd1bc72eb21d99c62")
        },
        [
            {
                "groupName" : "php",
                "groupAssigned" : "No",
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0880d13c9fc4c22a1d291")
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "groupName" : "android",
                "groupAssigned" : "No",
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0883513c9fc4c22a1d292")
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "groupName" : "ios",
                "groupAssigned" : "No",
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0883913c9fc4c22a1d293")
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "groupName" : "dotNet",
                "groupAssigned" : "No",
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0884213c9fc4c22a1d294")
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "groupName" : "testing",
                "groupAssigned" : "No",
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0885913c9fc4c22a1d295")
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "groupName" : "design",
                "groupAssigned" : "No",
                "_id" : ObjectId("56b0886213c9fc4c22a1d296")
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and my schema declaration like :

```
var userSchema  =   new mongoose.Schema({
    username    : {type:String},
    password    : {type:String},
    firstName   : {type:String},
    lastName    : {type:String},
    email       : {type:String},
    userVerified: {type:String},
    userType    : {type:String},
    userGroup   : [{groupName:{type:String},groupAssigned:{type:String}}]
},{collection:'user'});

var user    =   mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

Now I want to list all the array elements (here: `userGroup`),and username and I tried like:

```
user.find().select('userGroup').exec(function(err,rows){
    for (var i in rows)
    console.log(rows[i].username+' '+rows[i].userGroup);
});
```

it displays output like :

```
    **undefined** { _id: 56b086ccd1bc72eb21d99c62,
  groupAssigned: 'No',
  groupName: 'nodeJs' },{ '0': 
   { _id: 56b0880d13c9fc4c22a1d291,
     groupAssigned: 'No',
     groupName: 'php' } },{ '0': 
   { _id: 56b0883513c9fc4c22a1d292,
     groupAssigned: 'No',
     groupName: 'android' } },{ '0': 
   { _id: 56b0883913c9fc4c22a1d293,
     groupAssigned: 'No',
     groupName: 'ios' } },{ '0': 
   { _id: 56b0884213c9fc4c22a1d294,
     groupAssigned: 'No',
     groupName: 'dotNet' } },{ '0': 
   { _id: 56b0885913c9fc4c22a1d295,
     groupAssigned: 'No',
     groupName: 'testing' } },{ '0': 
   { _id: 56b0886213c9fc4c22a1d296,
     groupAssigned: 'No',
     groupName: 'design' } }
```

In the above output i achieve only the array of elements, but i want the username along with it, now the username is undefined. How it can be done?

Comment: I think something is wrong with your schema declaration since `userGroup` is an array with first entry as a object and every subsequent entry as an array with single objects.

Comment: please post your schema definition with the question

Comment: hi @Anbhav Mishra, thanks for your response, please look on my updated one.

Comment: If you want to `select` the `username` in the query, why not add `username` to your `select` condition?

Comment: yes i tried that, but it errors like : Error: Invalid select: select only takes 1 argument

Comment: @karthik Looks like you're using `select` wrong. Try `select('username userGroup')` : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Thank you very much it works. and i hope you are good at mongoose, kindly suggest me some referral links for mongoose join tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The username is not showing up because you're not including it in your select condition:

`user.find().select('username userGroup').exec...` should work fine

Docs on queries: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: As of you said i done, it brings the username and userGroup and includes some unwanted data like { '0': [Object] }... the ouput looks like [ { _id: 56b086ccd1bc72eb21d99c62, groupAssigned: 'No', groupName: 'nodeJs' }, { '0': [Object] }, { '0': [Object] }, { '0': [Object] }, { '0': [Object] }, { '0': [Object] }, { '0': [Object] } ] .How to avoid the { '0': [Object] } ?

Answer (score 0):

```
user.find({}, 'username userGroup', function(err, docs) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.log(docs);
});
```

Selective retrieving of fields with mongoose find method. Try if it works for you.

Comment: please mark one of the answers as right if it works. happy to help!!

Comment: As of you said i done, it brings the username and userGroup and includes some unwanted data like  { '0': [Object] }... the ouput looks like [ { _id: 56b086ccd1bc72eb21d99c62,
         groupAssigned: 'No',
         groupName: 'nodeJs' },
       { '0': [Object] },
       { '0': [Object] },
       { '0': [Object] },
       { '0': [Object] },
       { '0': [Object] },
       { '0': [Object] } ] .How to avoid the { '0': [Object] } ?